# How to call public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am using Java and Android Studio.  I need to change an image on the actionbar.  What I need to do is to change the image I am displaying on the actionbar based on a reading received from a remote  sensor. Therefore, I cannot use a clickable method but instead I have  some code that activates when the data is received from the sensor.  The code then analyzes the data and decides which of several images to display.  The program then needs to update the actionbar image.  This is the part I need your help on.  I think I should use onPrepareOptionsMenu to update the image.  However, I cannot seem to get the code correct to call onPrepareOptionsMenu.  In particular, onPrepareOptions uses parameters (Menu menu).  I cannot seem to specify the second menu properly as it always gives an error.  The code below gives:
"required android.view.Menu found int".  If I initialize menu with null I get a null reference error.  Any suggestions how to correct my code or maybe do something totally different to be able to update the image?  Thanks.  Below is my java code.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.clear(); // Clear the menu first

    Log.d(TAG, " Before inflation");
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
    Log.d(TAG, "Before the findItem");
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_batlevel).setIcon(R.drawable.low25);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Code to call the onPrepareOptionsMenu with:

```
            ...
            else if (dataType == 2.0) {
                Menu menu = (R.menu.gatt_services);
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);
                onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu);
            ...
```

XML code for the action bar.  The image I am trying to change is item id/menu_batlevel:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
          android:checkable="false"
          android:orderInCategory="1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_batlevel"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/discharged"
        android:title="BatLev"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_connect"
          android:title="@string/menu_connect"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_disconnect"
          android:title="@string/menu_disconnect"
          android:orderInCategory="101"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

---

My solution is shown below.  I put the if statements that update the image into the onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptions Before inflation");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gatt_services, menu);   
        ...
        if (dataType == 2.0){
            if (bat_level < 10) {
        MenuItem batItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_batlevel);
        batItem.setIcon(R.drawable.discharged);
            }
        ...
```

I added a class:

```
class VersionHelper
{
    static void refreshActionBarMenu(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

I call the class from my program:

```
...
                else if (dataType == 2.0) {
                    VersionHelper.refreshActionBarMenu(DeviceControlActivity.this);
...
```

The above code is working.  As you can tell, I am new to java so if you see a problem with this code or have a better method, please let me know.

Comment: Normally, you would not call onPrepareOptionsMenu yourself. So could you explain why you need to call it yourself?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Sorry but with you the posted code it is hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I updated the question to try to be more clear.  What I need to do is to dynamically change an image on the action bar.

Comment: Does the sensor not have listeners like buttons or other elements?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the image on an existing menu item, you can save a reference to the menu item when it's created, something like this:

```
private MenuItem photoMenuItem;

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_end_details, menu);

    // find the photo menu and save it
    photoMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.photoMenuItem);
}
```

Then when it's time to update the menu item, just call setIcon:

```
if (photoMenuItem != null)
{
    photoMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.camera_active);
}
```

If you want to decide whether or not to show a particular menu item, you can call setVisible instead of setIcon on the items whose presence may change.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for.  I also posted a different solution I found before I saw your comment.  Your looks more efficient.